# Update queryset on view without actually updating on database

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm trying to add a field "grade" to my users queryset. I have 3 models: Users, Subject and Exam. I don't think there is a way to calculate a user grade on the initial query like:

```
Users.objects.get(pk=x).annotate(grade=z)
```

because I have to call a method of the Subject model to calculate the total grade of that user for the subject, not only the grade for 1 exam (see the method below in the models description).

In my view I did:

```
user_obj = Users.object.get(pk=x).annotate(grade=Value(0, IntegerField()))
calculated_grade = subject.calculate_user_grade(user_obj)
user_obj.grade = calculated_grade
```

And then passed the user_obj to the template. But once it gets there the grade field I modified is already gone. I print "user_obj.grade" on view and it gives the correct value, then I print it on the template and it gives me 0, the initial value of the "annotate".

The models I use are the default user model in django and then

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def calculate_user_grade(self, user):
        points = 0
        exams = Exam.objects.filter(subject=self)
        for exam in exams:
            user_answer = ExamUser.objects.get(user=user, exam=exam)
            points += user_answer.points
        return points

class Exam(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    question = models.CharField()

class ExamUser(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: How do you pass the `user_obj` to the template? Can you show more of the view?

Answer (score 0):

A good question. From your question and codes, the issues is probably from parsing the **unsaved object from `view` to `template`**.

The short answer is to use `dictionary` instead of parsing the unsaved `object`.

```
user_obj = Users.object.get(pk=x)
calculated_grade = subject.calculate_user_grade(user_obj)
user_dict = dict(user_obj)
user_dict.setdefault('grade', calculated_grade)
```

Then parse the `user_dict` to your template.